# Find the $f(x)$ from the problem.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

A person at point $A$ in a lake is going to swim to the shore ST and walk to point $B$. He swims at 1.5 and walks at 4 miles/hour.If he gets to the shore at point $p$, $x$ miles from $s$, let $f(x)$ denote the time for his total swim and walk. Obtain the algebraic formula for $f(x)$. (edit: distance B to T is 6.)

[image]

I followed the right angle and average speed formula and simplified and got to $f(x) = \frac{650-120x}{11}$ but i don't know if it's correct. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: How far (perpendicular) from $B$ to the line $ST$ ?

Comment: sorry. I added it to the end of question.

Comment: But now you put the $6$ along the shoreline in the diagram. Is it also distance $6$ for the vertical from $B$ to line $ST$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $A$ to $p$ the distance is $d(A,p)=\sqrt{x^2+2^2}$, and from $p$ to $B$ the distance is $d(p,B)=\sqrt{(6-x)^2+6^2}.$ Each of these is using Pythagorean theorem to get lengths of hypotenuse. Then since "distance=rate*time" you have time=distance/rate, so the total time should be 
$$f(x)=\frac{d(A,p)}{1.5}+\frac{d(p,B)}{4}.$$